# Does office 365 and Gmail provide alias for email id and domain?

Tags: email, dns, gmail, office365, alias

I would like to know if Office365 and Google Suit provides "Alias" for email id and domain. Actually, Alias is generally used to create 2 email IDs like abc@xyz.com and abc@pqr.com and both the emails coming to the same email id.

If anyone is aware about the same then please let me know.

Comment: An email alias is an alternate address that points to a user's existing Gmail account. Mail sent to the user's primary address (the one you created for their Google Apps account) and any email aliases you add, all appear in the user's same Gmail inbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Exchange Online you can register multiple domains against a single account and use them for incoming emails, but outgoing email is currently always sent from the primary address defined for a user

so (eg) if you have abc@xyz.com as the primary and abc@pqr.com as an alias, then incoming email to both addresses will be delivered to the abc@xyz.com mailbox and replies always sent from that address

Suggest adding a vote to [this item](https://office365.uservoice.com/forums/273494-outlook-and-calendar/suggestions/8518849-send-with-alias-mailadresses) to see if MS can/will address it...